# Como abrir um PDF utilizando Totalcross?

Tags: java, pdf, totalcross

Em meu aplicativo feito em Totalcross, faço uma chamada REST e o mesmo retorna um `byte[]` no qual converto em um pdf e salvo em um diretório específico dentro do dispositivo.
Nesse fluxo, está tudo ok.

A minha necessidade é.. dentro do aplicativo, preciso abrir o PDF ou sugerir para o usuário abrir com algum aplicativo em específico como é feito por exemplo em Android, utilizando Intent:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17453242/1132083

Existe alguma forma de sugerir ao usuário ou abrir o PDF através do meu aplicativo?

Comment: Qual plataforma alvo? Eu lembro de ter disponível para Android alguma coisa nesse sentido, não lembro das outras...

Comment: Veja se esse link ajuda: https://gitlab.com/totalcross/TotalCross/wikis/Features/open%20known%20files%20in%20Android; caso ajudar, transformo em uma resposta completa aqui

Comment: Preciso para Android, iOS e Simulador.

Comment: Tentei utilizar: 'Vm.exec("url", pdf, 0, true);'  onde pdf é o caminho para o arquivo pdf.. tentei no "Simulador" e não tive êxito.. não teve nenhuma ação..

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado possui alguma sugestão para contornar isso? Caso contrário.. terei que desenvolver essa funcionalidade de outra forma..

Comment: Acredito que esta pergunta possa ser fechada pois não possui tal solução com Totalcross.

Comment: O fato de nao funcionar no simulador nao significa que nao funciona nas plataformas. O TotalCrossAPI tem exemplos de como abrir um PDF. Procure por sys / external viewers

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme. Já havia feito com os viewers do Sys, e realmente abriu o PDF em ambas plataformas.. Porém, tive outro problema.. No Android, acredito que ele chame uma Intent solicitando um APP para abrir o PDF.. Porém, no iOS, é aberto em um componente UIWebView... e neste caso, impossibilita de 'compartilhar' o PDF.. Pois tal funcionalidade que eu preciso implementar requer que além de abrir, possa compartilhar o PDF via Whatsapp, por exemplo.
De qualquer forma, obrigado por sua resposta.