# É possível salvar um arquivo em "Downloads" utilizando Totalcross?

Tags: java, totalcross

Para contextualizar.. 
Inicialmente eu estava tentando implementar a abertura de um PDF utilizando Totalcross como pode ser visto nessa questão: [Como abrir um PDF utilizando Totalcross?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244692/11695)

Porém, não há uma solução para tal problema.
Sendo assim, uma outra saída é salvar o arquivo no dispositivo do cliente, e apresentar o caminho/diretório para que o mesmo possa navegar até o local e abrir o arquivo PDF.

Pois bem, criar diretórios e inserir o arquivo em tal é possível fazer.

A minha dúvida é.. existe algo que o Totalcross implemente o diretório padrão de downloads das plataformas?

Como por exemplo, em código nativo Android, é possível acessar a pasta de "Downloads" utilizando o seguinte trecho:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

Desde já, agradeço o apoio! :)

Comment: Precisei fazer o mesmo, porém a unica solução que encontrei foi abrir uma url com um botão "download" deixar para o navegador fazer o download

Comment: Como ficou no iOS, deu certo isso também?

Comment: Precisei do recurso apenas para Android, então não sei dizer como ficou no iOS